# How often are user repositories abused?

Tags: linux, package-management, malware

No matter which distribution you use, you probably have a package manager and most likely installed one or two packages from an "unofficial source", meaning a regular user has provided it. As installing software with helper tools like `apt`, `rpm`, `pacman` and so on, is incredibly easy, it is very tempting to just press OK, accept, OK, accept,... and have it quickly installed.

So the thought of including malware with the package is not far. Is this a big concern for the regular user and by that I mean, are there any reported cases of abuse? If you remember/know cases please provide the source and references.

Note that this is not about opinion about the general safety, but showing cases where user package repositories have been misused. I hope I don't violate the guidelines.

Comment: I don't think this is really answerable, or a Unix/Linux problem at all. You get the same thing with Windows - installing stuff from random locations will get you random malware. Some apps/frameworks do stuff like telling you to run `wget http://wherever | bash` or similar to install themselves; same deal, no package manager required,  bad habit to get into.

Comment: As for whether it happens - main repos and their mirrors are a much juicier target. Has happened before (e.g. http://lwn.net/Articles/62499/).

Comment: @Mat Did gentoo not use GPG keys for the manifests back then? It seems like they would've had to compromise the key as well otherwise their [Manifest](https://devmanual.gentoo.org/general-concepts/manifest/) would never have been properly signed.

Comment: @Bratchley: that's a while ago, I don't think they had all the security measures in place yet. That's largely irrelevant in the case TomTom is concerned about, i.e. random repos provided by unofficial sources. You'll have to trust their "unofficial" GPG key (or ignore the "this package is not signed" warning, or whatever) to use the repo.

Comment: Given that this question is not distribution-specific, this is rather a broad question. I can imagine a reasonable question asking, for example, what security features Debian has implemented to prevent malware package from getting on user computers. And a similar one for Gentoo for example. But that isn't what you are asking.

Comment: @FaheemMitha This question is too broad, not because it depends on the distribution, but because it depends on the source. Anyone can put up a website from which packages can be downloaded.

Comment: @Gilles that's true. The poster is asking about any user repositories whatsoever.